# How do I manage programs that run in multiple consoles?

Tags: console, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative Windows command shell and console?](https://superuser.com/questions/87441/alternative-windows-command-shell-and-console)

I have a script that starts 7 or 8 different c++ server modules that all open in console windows on a windows machine. I've been looking for a way to run all of these in a single, tabbed window. I've tried a few programs out there, but they are mostly cmd.exe replacements and aren't really designed for running programs like this. Has anyone else run into this and found a good solution?

Comment: Which cmd.exe replacement have you tried? There's many listed here which support tabs: [Alternative Windows command shell and console?](http://superuser.com/questions/87441/alternative-windows-command-shell-and-console). Any of those work/not work for your situation?

Comment: Cygwin + puttycyg + tmux/screen